# Connect AngularJs to local server php MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, angularjs, ionic-framework

Total beginner question (apologize in advance for the stupidity :( )

I am trying to learn how to develop apps using **ionic framework/angular**. 
I created a simple news feed (UI part of it anyway).

I then installed **MySQL**, **PHP** and **Apache** on my Mac (**MAMP**). I have created some tables and inserted some dummy data.

Now, I am completely lost on what kind of routine/procedure to write on my server, and what code to write in my **Angular** service so i can show the dummy data in my app?

Basically, how do these two discreet "things" on my system know how to connect and exchange data?

I googled it for few days, but most tutorials don't seem to address this basic question.

I don't actually expect somebody to take me through the steps, but if you can **point me to some tutorials/resources on this**, it would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The premise of the question is wrong. You consume an API, don't connect.

Comment: I guess so. I was trying to ask the question in layman terms, because, like i said, i am new to all this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to think in terms of web/RESTful services to expose data to your Angular app. I can point you to a couple of introductory tutorials on the MEAN stack (MongoDB, Express, Angular, Node), but you'll get the idea:

[Learn to Build Modern Web Apps with MEAN](https://thinkster.io/mean-stack-tutorial/)

[Mastering MEAN: Introducing the MEAN stack](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/wa-mean1/index.html)

[Several references to online resources, by ericdouglas](https://github.com/ericdouglas/MEAN-Learning)

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using AngularJS, your frontend app is a single-page app I suppose. All data your frontend app based on is provided by your backend, here is PHP/MySQL.

You need to use PHP to create a REST service to provide JSON data, which can be consumed by AngularJS app. While MySQL is behind your PHP app as a storage provider, it doesn't talk to your AngularJS app directly.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! ya, i guess i get that part. So that means i should read up on creating Rest service before i can proceed? also, if you can point to any tutorials/resources that shows how to put all this together, it would be helpful.